# exception while calling the scanner document using java

Tags: java, windows-7-x64, twain

hi i am using java and i am using twain jar to implement read the scanned document from scanner. i am using 64 bit java and 64 bit windows 7. and i added twain 64 related dll in system32. and i am getting these exception like

```
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainFailureException: Failed during call to twain source.
    cc=No Data Source
    rc=1
Source Manager Open
Source Manager Open
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainIOException: uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainScanner.setException:
    Failed during call to twain source.
    cc=No Data Source
    rc=1
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainScanner.signalException(TwainScanner.java:131)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.signalException(jtwain.java:287)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.cbexecute(jtwain.java:243)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.nstart(Native Method)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.access$200(jtwain.java:12)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain$1.run(jtwain.java:338)
uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainFailureException: Failed during call to twain source.
    cc=No Data Source
    rc=1
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainSourceManager.call(TwainSourceManager.java:27)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainIdentity.open(TwainIdentity.java:70)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainSource.open(TwainSource.java:99)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainSourceManager.openSource(TwainSourceManager.java:93)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.cbexecute(jtwain.java:234)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.nstart(Native Method)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain.access$200(jtwain.java:12)
    at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jtwain$1.run(jtwain.java:338)
```

## my java class is

```
public class TwainExample implements ScannerListener{

      static TwainExample app;  

      Scanner scanner;

      public TwainExample(String[] argv)throws ScannerIOException{
       scanner=scanner.getDevice();
       String scanners[]=scanner.getDeviceNames();
       for(String scann:scanners){
           System.out.println(scann);
       }
        scanner.addListener(this);    
        scanner.acquire();
      }

      public void update(ScannerIOMetadata.Type type, ScannerIOMetadata metadata){
        if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED)){
          BufferedImage image=metadata.getImage();
          System.out.println("Have an image now!");
          try{
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("mmsc_image.png"));
          }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.NEGOTIATE)){
          ScannerDevice device=(ScannerDevice) metadata.getDevice();
          try{
//          device.setShowUserInterface(true);
//          device.setShowProgressBar(true);
//          device.setResolution(100);
          }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.STATECHANGE)){
          System.err.println(metadata.getStateStr());
          if(metadata.isFinished()){
            System.exit(0);
          }
        }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.EXCEPTION)){
          metadata.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] argv){
        try{
          app=new TwainExample(argv);
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which twain jar are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you don't have 64-bit TWAIN driver on your machine. You can download and install the [64-bit TWAIN sample data source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/twain-samples/files/TWAIN%202%20Sample%20Data%20Source/TWAIN%20DS%202.1.3/) and try again.

Comment: thanks for your reply but again i am getting the below exception.uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.TwainSource.enable:
 scan timed out Close data source.

Comment: Were you able to scan using your TWAIN driver via another application?

Comment: no i don't can you provide any code for this if you have..?

Comment: can you plz tell me about dll files why it is require for image acquisition.

Comment: Would you be more specific with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to interact with scanner device to acquire the scanned document.

Comment: You may try [Twack 64-bit](http://www.twain.org/scannerdriverdevelopers/specification-and-tools.html) to test if your scanner is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution was to install jdk java 32bit.